# npm start produces error in React app on WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

I see the question has been asked before but none of the solutions seems to help me.

Error that I am getting, I tried to remove the `node_modules` directory as well. And then reinstalled npm. Still the same error.

1. `rm -rf node_modules`
2. `npm install`
3. `npm start`
   -- same error

Even tried deleting the `package-lock.json`, but same error on npm start.

Node version - v10.15.3
NPM version - 6.4.1

```
Aryans-MacBook-Pro:react-new-app aryanarora$ npm start

> react-new-app@0.1.0 start /Users/aryanarora/Desktop/The Web Developer Bootcamp/01 All Practice Files /js<:>/Jon Duckett/react-new-app
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! react-new-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-new-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aryanarora/.npm/_logs/2019-04-29T06_08_07_273Z-debug.log
```

After doing `npm list --depth 0 | grep react-scripts`
output as follows:

```
Aryans-MacBook-Pro:react-new-app aryanarora$ npm list --depth 0 | grep react-scripts
└── react-scripts@3.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev, required by tsutils@3.10.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@*, required by ts-pnp@1.1.2
```

Package.json File

```
{
  "name": "react-new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a permission issue ( ENOENT - Error No entry)
May I know what operating system that you are using?

Comment: Can you append `package.json`? and result of
`npm list --depth 0 | grep react-scripts`

Comment: @DularaMalindu MacOs version - 10.12.6

Comment: @JayLim sorry what do u mean by that? the project already has a package.json file in it.

Comment: @AryanArora, I assume you are using [create-react-app/package.json](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/package.json).
It looks your local machine(computer) can't find command `react-scripts`.
Output of `npm list --depth 0 | grep react-scripts` would be helpful. Can you run it?

Comment: @JayLim the IDE (webstorm) creates the project itself in background. So i don't know which command it uses for creating the project

Comment: @JayLim I updated the question with the output. Please have a look

Comment: @AryanArora Thank you for your update.
Hmm, I've set webstorm like you, however it works well for me(node v11.6.0, npm 6.5.0). For more digging, can you run `ls -al node_modules/react-scripts/bin/` ?

Comment: @JayLim Sure, total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 aryanarora  staff   102 Apr 28 23:16 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 aryanarora  staff   374 Apr 28 23:17 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 aryanarora  staff  1994 Oct 26  1985 react-scripts.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192545/discussion-between-jay-lim-and-aryan-arora).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the node and npm itself.
Try to uninstall node from your machine completely by using Homebrew or NVM, whichever you used to install node. Else you have to do it manually.

Follow the steps in this link - https://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/

Next install the LTS node from the official website (https://nodejs.org/en/), this should solve the issue.

One thing i also found out to be helpful was to change the directory. My directory had folder named "`</>js`" which I beleive created some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure `React-scripts` node module installed, to check this, please do below steps.

- install `npm install` again
- Go to node_modules --> react-scripts (make sure folder exists)
- Run `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue of npm version. Please try some suggestions.

1. Uninstall yarn `npm uninstall -g yarn`
2. Do a cache clean.  `npm cache clean -f`
3. If still doesn't work, try to downgrade/upgrade your npm version to npm 5.4.2 or npm 5.3.*.

   `npm install -g npm@5.4.2`